# Django website that refreshes page on new postgres entry to provide realtime updates to user

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to automatically refresh / reload the django webpage in the users webbrowser when a new entry is found in the database. Currently i use a meta refresh as a temporary solution. I have installed and am using pgpubsub. So i can get a notification when there is a new item in the database. But how can i trigger django to reload the website?

```
import pgpubsub
pubsub = pgpubsub.connect(host="localhost",database="somedb",user="somebody")
pubsub.listen('pg_news');
for e in pubsub.events():
     print(e.payload)
```

any ideas are welcome

Comment: This is a very common thing to do. You can use periodical asynchronous calls, long polling, WebSockets or other techniques. You can learn about popular WebSockets with Django here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: thanks petr for pointing out to the right direction! :)